# Lumen package. How to load custom validation.php messages file?

Tags: laravel, validation, package, translation, lumen

I'm creating my first package for lumen 6.x. I'm able to use my own translated messages from `/resources/lang/es/messages.php` within my package but for some reason, validation messages are not working, in fact, the `/resources/lang/es/validation.php` is ignored.

I'm guessing that's something related to the way that validator is implemented in the controller since translations are correctly loaded from my Provider, therefore I assume that it's being loaded too.

My `/resources/lang/es/validation.php` looks like:

```
<?php

return [
    'required' => 'El campo :attribute es obligatorio.',
];
```

My boot function within service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
   $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/lang', 'locations');
   $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../database/migrations');
   $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/../routes/web.php');

   // Publishing is only necessary when using the CLI.
   if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
       $this->bootForConsole();
   }
}
```

The store function in Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) return $validator->errors();

    $resource = Country::create($request->toArray());

    return response()->json([
        'message'  => __('locations::messages.store_success'),
        'resource' => $resource
    ]);
}
```

Also in my main `.env` lumen file I've added `APP_LOCALE=es` which works perfect for translations.

So the problem is that I'm not able to show translated message for required `name` field.

BTW, con can look the whole code in my testing git repository (Please ignore States and Cities stuff since it under development).
https://github.com/Imboga/Locations

Thanks in advance

---

Edit:
I also tried with this, but no luck so far

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $resource = Country::create($request->toArray());

        return response()->json([
            'message'  => __('locations::messages.store_success'),
            'resource' => $resource
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. For those facing the same issue, what I've done is to add third and fourth parameters in `validate()` method referencing the localized file:

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required'
        ], trans('locations::validation'), trans('locations::validation.attributes') );

        $resource = Country::findOrFail($request->id);
        $resource->update($request->toArray());

        return response()->json([
            'message'  => __('locations::messages.update_success'),
            'resource' => $resource
        ]);
    }
```

The fourth parameter has to point to the attributes array within `validation.php`.

On the other hand, with this change, I'm able to overwrite my package `validation.php` file in main app by adding a `validation.php` in `resources/lang/vendor/locations/`

FYI, my `validation.php` looks like:

```
<?php

return [
    'required' => 'El campo :attribute es obligatorio.',

    'attributes' => [
        'name' => 'Nombre'
    ],

];
```

Not sure if this is the best approach, but it's working so far. Any improvement will be appreciated.